# DBT test error dbt internally failed to run test

Tags: dbt

I wrote a simple generic dbt test and I get error saying `dbt internally failed to execute test.dbtlearn.no_nulls_in_dim_listings_cleansed: Returned 0 rows, but expected 1 row`

I did not find any solution for this. Anyone has any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you’re running an earlier version of dbt. Originally tests returned a **count** of failing rows (ie one row with a single value) but now they need a **set** of failing rows (one row per failure).

It sounds like your dbt version is expecting the former when your test is written for the latter, I’d try modifying your test or even better upgrading to a more recent version of dbt.

Comment: I checked dbt --version and it shows  - Ahead of latest version!.

Comment: What version exactly? Maybe you've run into a bug on an unreleased version?

Comment: I have the same problem. I am using 1.3.0b2, it is because of this code that checks number of rows: https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/blob/56783446dbc765d93c43afad2b763302f034ef6b/core/dbt/task/test.py#L154